# Test Class for Servicemax Webservice

Tags: apex, webservices

I am trying to write the test class for the servicemax managed package and I search their website for document to get started but there is nothing I could find. I have tried to write the test class my own but I am so lost. Any help is appreciated to get started on this.
Here's website I referred to : https://help.servicemax.com/articles/#!servicemax-21-1-publication/sample-web-service-for-updating-header-record

Here's the class:

```
 global class TripWorkOrder {
    
  webservice static SVMXC.SFM_WrapperDef.SFM_PageData ReturnTripWO(SVMXC.SFM_WrapperDef.SFM_TargetRecord request) {

        SVMXC.SFM_WrapperDef.SFM_PageData pagedata = new SVMXC.SFM_WrapperDef.SFM_PageData(); 
        map<String,Schema.SObjectType> Allobj = new map<String, Schema.SObjectType>(); 
        map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = new Map<String, Schema.SObjectType>(); 
        gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
        if(gd.size() > 0) 
        { 
            for(Schema.SObjectType s : gd.values()) 
            { 
               Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result = s.getDescribe(); 
               Allobj.put(result.getName(), s); 
            } 
        } 
        SVMXC.SFM_ServicesDef def = new SVMXC.SFM_ServicesDef(); 
        Sobject headerSobj = def.SFM_Page_GetHeaderRecord(request, Allobj); 
        SVMXC__Service_Order__c wo = new SVMXC__Service_Order__c(); 
        wo = (SVMXC__Service_Order__c) headerSobj; 
        


        map<String,List<Sobject>> detailSobjectMap = new map<String, List<Sobject>>();
        detailSobjectMap = def.SFM_Page_GetDetailRecords(request, Allobj);


        if (wo.Category__c == 'Associate') {
          List<Contact> contactList = new List <Contact>();
          for(String str : detailSobjectMap.keyset()) { 
            List<SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c> lstWoLines = new List<SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c>(); 
            lstWoLines = detailSobjectMap.get(str); 
             Contact c = [SELECT Id, associate_Trips_Taken__c, Location_Community__r.associate_Trips_Max__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :lstWoLines[0].Contact__c LIMIT 1];
            if(lstWoLines.size() > 1) { 
              throw new TooManyPassengersException('If Work Category = Associate, there can only be one passenger');
              return pagedata;                          
            } else {
                // some more code//
              }
            
            }
        }
    }
```

I have created data for SVMXC__Service_Order__c and contact. Here's my test class.

```
List<SVMXC.SFM_WrapperDef> testMapList = new List<SVMXC.SFM_WrapperDef>();
        SVMXC.SFM_WrapperDef.SVMXMap testmap = new SVMXC.SFM_WrapperDef.SVMXMap();
        testmap.key = 'WorkOrder_ID';
        testmap.value = newWorkOrder.Id; //SVMXC__Service_Order__c id
        testMapList.add(testmap);
        Test.startTest();
        testMapList = TripWorkOrder.ReturnTripWO(newWorkOrder.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
```